# Sort object by using specific character

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, console

I have a script block which contain one line: **`Get-NetTCPConnection | Select State | Sort -Descending`** the result for me is:

```
      State
      -----
     Listen
      Bound
      Bound
Established
Established
      Bound
     Listen
      Bound
      Bound
     Listen
```

as you see the state 'Listen' is a first result and extra.
**Now:**  I want to sort result [*objects*] by my own character, such as 'b or E'

**Here** is a wrong result, which I mean that:

```
  State
  -----
  Established
  Established
  Listen
  Bound
  Bound
```

Comment: What is a "right" result for you?  The `State` has a type of `Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.NetTCPConnection.State` which translates to a `.value__` property as a `byte` type.

Comment: I know it, but you know the sorting always is A to Z or Z to A, I want to 'E to otherChar'. in fact I want to the 'ESTABLISHED's going to the first result in my example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort descending on `State.ToString` then do (whatever sense this makes).

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object State |
    Sort-Object -Property @{e={$($_.State).ToString() -replace 'ESTABLISHED','zzzz'}} -Desc
```

Comment: it's something, I want to the 'ESTABLISHED' which is first litter 'E', to be the first in the result.

Comment: Simply replace the value to be first with something that will be first. See changed answer.